# java-oracle9i /10g connectivity

Tags: java, oracle

i was trying java and oracle 9i connectivity for a long time i tried different ways the program is getting compiled very well at execution time its showing me an error stating " no classdeffounderror" wat shud i do?please sumbody provide me a solution to this(i tried setting the class path in all ways... )i need it as soon as posible .thank you..

Comment: How about showing the exact command you are executing and the exact error you are getting?

Comment: What class is not found?

Comment: Are you using the OCI or the Thin driver?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the Oracle driver jar onto your classpath.

If you are using an older JDBC driver then you may wish to download a newer one from here

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_111060.html

They're generally backwards compatible.

Also check that your driver class has been loaded and is correct.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

See for a code example http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/edu/db/oracle-and-java